# Is there any open source library to convert a presentation (pptx/ppt) to HTML - for collaboration?

Tags: html, export, powerpoint

I am working on a project which requires users to be able to collaborate over a presentation(not edit, but view it in sync, with some more interactions).
I am considering the approach to render it as an HTML in browser, with my viewer wrapper maintaining sync between different users, and adding more functionality.

Is there some library which can help me achieve this, because I am not looking to write an animation engine at this point.

Also, is there any alternate approach which I should be exploring?

Comment: Powerpoint has an option to "export to web" (Take a look at "File" menu). I wouldn't recomend editing the exported content tho...

Comment: @CarlosCarucce It's best to specify which version(s) of PowerPoint you mean so that it's clear to OP. Windows PPT from 2010 onward doesn't have this option on the File Menu. Amitabha's suggestion works for 2010 but not 2013 and later.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. There is a [way](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/980553/the-options-to-save-a-presentation-as-a-webpage-are-not-available-in-t).

1. In PowerPoint 2010, open the presentation that you want to export to HTML.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.
4. In the Immediate pane, type the
   following, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   `ActivePresentation.SaveAs "C:\users\amitabha\desktop\filename.htm", ppSaveAsHTML, msoFalse`

Note: Modify the command as per your drive and username.

Comment: I am looking to do this programatically on a server which will not have MS powerpoint installed.